# gvim: Make the mouse follow CTRL-W_j and CTRL-W_k

Tags: gvim, vim-windows, linux, mouse

I run a Linux/GNOME laptop where the focus follows the mouse, and I have vim's `mousefocus` feature turned on, so the selected viewport follows the mouse, too. But when I try to switch viewports using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> (AKA, in vim help, `CTRL-W_j` or `CTRL-W_k`), the active viewport stays as whichever one the mouse is over. [**UPDATE**: I've looked at this issue more carefully, and what actually happens is that the mouse cursor jumps to the centre of vim—not the centre of what vim calls a 'window', but what the window manager calls a window. And then whatever vim 'window' is under the cursor gets the focus.]

The thing is, this is a new problem. I have a .vimrc file that's evolved since the 1990s, through dozens of machines on multiple platforms, and I don't remember having to deal with this issue before. Unfortunately, I don't have my old laptop to compare it with, and for various reasons, I made do without my .vimrc file on my new laptop until today. But other than it being an updated laptop, running a newer version of Linux Mint (Cinnamon) and a newer version of vim, and loading (seemingly unrelated) extensions via a plug-in manager, it's essentially the same setup I've had for years. (I have `set mouse=a`, FWIW, which again is what it's been set to since before the turn of the century.)

I think what happened on my previous laptops is that the mouse followed the active viewport in vim, if I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> to change it. I've been looking for a plugin or setting to make it do that again, but I can't find it. So perhaps this behaviour has changed between version 7.3 and 8.0?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `<C-w>n` creates a new window, rather than move. That said, this sounds like the feature working "as intended" (i.e., the focus stays with the mouse pointer). Disabling `'mousefocus'` is probably the best bet. Setting `mouse=a` will still alllow you to click if need be

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found having `mousefocus` turned off one of the most frustrating things about the defaults. Nearly 30 years of X-windows/GNOME got me _really_ used to just moving the mouse and typing, not needing the extra click, yet still being able to Alt+Tab between windows when the mouse was less convenient. Vim always worked the same way; when I changed viewports with Ctrl+W j/k, it either moved the mouse for me, or it ignored `mousefocus` until I moved the mouse again. I can't remember exactly, but it worked for me since I retired my Windows '98 laptop.

Comment: And yes, I typed the wrong key combination—thanks. Looks like I'm not that good recalling key combinations from muscle memory.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: I removed your suggestions about new tags, and added the `vim-windows` tag, as `window` is the standard Vim terminology for `viewport`. Having `viewport` as a tag synonym for `vim-windows` might be a good idea, but I suspect that `mousefocus` is a bit narrow for a new tag. Either way, I think asking a question on the [meta site](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place for such requests. (As in, it's more likely to elicit a response/results there).

Comment: FWIW, This works how you'd like it to in my installation of v8.1 MacVim. However, it does _not_ work as documented: `:help mousef` states: `When changing the window layout or window focus in another way, the mouse pointer is moved to the window with keyboard focus` but for me, when switching windows with the keyboard, the mouse pointer stays where it is. Possibly worth raising an issue on the Vim github repository about this issue?

Comment: @Rich: Thanks. I actually got the term 'viewport' from vim help (e.g. `:help split`), but looking again, it turns out that a viewport is to a range of lines within a file, and that it goes in a window.

Comment: @MichaelScheper See `:help window`. A window _is_ a viewport, but the majority of the Vim documentation (and community) uses the term “window”: `:helpgrep viewport` only returns 4 hits, and they’re all just being used to describe what a “window” is.